# How can I perform a Spring Data JPA Query using an Enum in my circumstance?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

First sorry this is long but I wanted to provide all information possible.

I am working on a much larger query that will build on this hence the reason I am not taking an easier or other approaches. In addition I can't really change the way we implemented the DB and Domain Objects.

My problem is I can't get a Spring Data JPA Query to work with an Enum. The field is an Enum in the DB as well. Here is the abbreviated code.

The SQL for the 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE my_order (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TYPE ORDER_STATE as ENUM ('new', 'open', 'closed');
CREATE CAST (CHARACTER VARYING AS ORDER_STATE) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;

CREATE TABLE my_order_history (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    order_state ORDER_STATE NOT NULL,
    order_id INT REFERENCES my_order
);
```

Here is the corresponding Domain Objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_order")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date creationDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OrderHistory> orderHistories;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_order_history")
public class OrderHistory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "order_date ")
    private Date orderDate;

    @Column(name = "order_state")
    @Convert(converter = OrderStateConverter.class)
    private OrderState orderState

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order order;
}
```

Here is the converter:

```
@Component
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class OrderStateConverter implement AttributeConverter<OrderState, String> {
   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn(OrderState attribute) {
       return attribute.getValue;
   }

   @Override
   public OrderState convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
      return OrderState.fromValue(dbData);
   }
}
```

Here is the Enum:

```
public enum OrderState {
   NEW("new"), OPEN("open"), CLOSED("closed");

   @Getter
   private String value;

   private OrderState(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public static OrderState fromValue(String value) {
      for (OrderState orderState : values()) {
         if (orderState.getValue().equals(value)) {
             return orderState;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Here is my Spring Repo. I am putting the 3 ways I have tried and then below I will give you the exceptions I am receiving with each:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Long> {
   @Query("SELECT o FROM Order o JOIN o.orderHistories oh WHERE oh.orderState = :orderState")
   List<Order> getOrdersByOrderState1(@Param("orderState") OrderState orderState);

   @Query("SELECT o FROM Order o JOIN o.orderHistories oh WHERE oh.orderState = :orderState")
   List<Order> getOrdersByOrderState2(@Param("orderState") String orderState);

   @Query("SELECT o FROM Order o JOIN o.orderHistories oh WHERE oh.orderState = :#(#orderState?.getValue())")
   List<Order> getOrdersByOrderState3(@Param("orderState") OrderState orderState);
}
```

For #1 when I provide an OrderState enum I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgres.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: order_state = character varying
   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need explicit type casts.
```

For #2 when I provide OrderState.getValue(), which is a String, I get the following exception:

```
java.jang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [new] did not match expected type [com.testing.enums.OrderState (n/a)]
```

For #3 when I provide an OrderState enum I get the following exception (same as #2):

```
java.jang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [new] did not match expected type [com.testing.enums.OrderState (n/a)]
```

Basically I try to send in the enum and get an error but I also get an error when I try to send in a String. Is there anything I can do? What is exactly happening?

Comment: please share the complete code of `OrderState.class` in order to be able to inspect it as well

Comment: try to remove from database `CREATE CAST (CHARACTER VARYING AS ORDER_STATE) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;` and try once again with your #1 option

Comment: Added complete OrderState class

Comment: I can try to remove it to see if that fixes the problem. There was a reason why this was added though off the top of my head I don't remember why. I am not quite sure if I can remove it but at least I can try to see if this works.

Comment: Removed the "CREATE CAST" line and retried with no success. Same error. Also tried #3 option with it removed just in case and that returned the same error as well.

Comment: So got it to work with doing a cast to string: "..WHERE CAST(osh.orderState AS string) = :orderState" and pass in a String instead of an OrderState. For some reason didn't work when trying to cast to the enum (using the full path) and passing in an OrderState which is confusing. Anyway, I will put this as the answer unless someone else comes up with something better.